# How to execute an URL with Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone, arduino, httpwebrequest

I need to execute an URL from a button in my WP app:

I tried this code but it doesn't work more than once:

```
private void btnLedOn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://192.168.0.1/?ledon"));
   request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(OnGettingResponse), request);
}
private void OnGettingResponse(IAsyncResult ar)
{
   var req = ar.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
   var response = (HttpWebResponse)req.EndGetResponse(ar);
   var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
}
```

I don't need any response just the just the URL to be executed so my LED will turn ON/OFF.
Any easier way to do this or to reset the request so it will work more than once?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`HttpClient` (check this link)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/02/18/portable-httpclient-for-net-framework-and-windows-phone.aspx).

It's the modern approach to HTTP of modern .NET Framework and it works better with REST-style requests since you'll find direct shortcuts to perform GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD and other verbs' resource requests.

Comment: I got but the problem is the same (it only works once),my code:
        private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
            webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("http://192.168.0.1/?ledon");
            webBrowserTask.Show();
        }

        private void btnLedOff_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var uri = new Uri("http://192.168.0.1/?ledoff");
            GetTheGoodStuff(uri);
        }

Comment: @user3504358 Throwing code in comments isn't the way to solve problems here... BTW if it works once, the problem should be in another point...

Comment: Sorry, but do you have any idea how could I solve that? How can I reset the request or something like that? Anyway thanks.

Comment: @user3504358 HttpClient should be used as a singleton: one instance per application. Try to don't create a new instance for each request, reuse it. Maybe this is your problem.